# How to get light to pass through my shader

Tags: godot, godot-shader-language

I have a plane that has a shader material attached to it to generate perlin noise. I'd like for my light to pass through it so that it can cast shadows on the stuff below.

[image]

Here is my shader:

```
shader_type spatial;

uniform float scale: hint_range(0.1, 10.0) = 2.0;
uniform float speed: hint_range(0.0, 5.0) = 1.0;
uniform vec4 cloud_color: source_color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
uniform vec4 background_color: source_color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

float rand(vec2 n) {
    return fract(sin(dot(n, vec2(12.9898, 4.1414))) * 43758.5453);
}

float noise(vec2 n) {
    const vec2 d = vec2(0.0, 1.0);
    vec2 b = floor(n), f = smoothstep(vec2(0.0), vec2(1.0), fract(n));
    return mix(mix(rand(b), rand(b + d.yx), f.x), mix(rand(b + d.xy), rand(b + d.yy), f.x), f.y);
}

void vertex() {
    VERTEX = VERTEX;
    NORMAL = normalize((MODEL_NORMAL_MATRIX * vec3(NORMAL)).xyz);
    UV = (UV + vec2(0.5, 0.5)) * 2.0;
}

void fragment() {
    vec2 uv = UV;
    float noise_value = noise(uv * scale + TIME * speed);
    vec4 color = mix(background_color, cloud_color, noise_value);
    ALBEDO = color.rgb;
    ALPHA = color.a;
}
```